# Add Custom Attributes to Core Rss Block Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to add extra toggle button to core gutenberg blocks and all are working fine except widget blocks and specially rss block.

- Added one button
- on button click add new attribute
- that attribute is not saving and block crashes

Here is the render API path:

```
domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/block-renderer/core/rss?context=edit&attributes%5Bcolumns%5D=2&attributes%5BblockLayout%5D=list&attributes%5BfeedURL%5D=https%3A%2F%domain.com%2Fblog%2F&attributes%5BitemsToShow%5D=5&attributes%5BdisplayExcerpt%5D=false&attributes%5BdisplayAuthor%5D=false&attributes%5BdisplayDate%5D=false&attributes%5BexcerptLength%5D=55&attributes%5Bdatatext%5D=el1683204085047&post_id=2&_locale=user
```

It shows 400 Bad request and if you check that Rest API URL there is **datatext** attribute which is custom attribute I'm trying to add.

**Error: react.js?ver=18.2.0:1120 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {error, errorMsg}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

Please suggest me the best way to add extra attribute to core/rss wordpress block.

Comment: When the block crashes, can you please get the error message from the browser console and add to your question if possible?

Comment: I added error to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your error in WP 6.2 on the `core/rss` block. Extending the block with a new attribute via the filter `blocks.registerBlockType` followed by editing then saving worked until a `feedURL` was added.

As the RSS block uses server side rendering, I reviewed the [render_callback](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/rss/index.php) code as the [ServerSideRender](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/63991c128883b35fd29f704fa78c1fc0fc829c72/packages/server-side-render/src/server-side-render.js#L56) error read:

> Error loading block: Invalid parameter(s): attributes

after adding `feedURL`, eg:

**No error**

```html
<!-- wp:rss {"datatext":"test"} /-->
```

**Error**

```html
<!-- wp:rss {"feedURL":"https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=wordpress-gutenberg\\u0026sort=newest","datatext":"test"} /-->
```

**Updated Answer**

On further testing, I confirmed using `addFilter('blocks.registerBlockType', ...);` in JavaScript directly causes the `Invalid parameter(s)` error.

When PHP renders a dynamic block on the front end, the block validation fails as the `block.json` attributes don't match the attributes saved in the markup.

**Solution**

Use the [`register_block_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_block_type_args/) filter in PHP to overwrite the blocks default `render_callback` and register an extra parameter at the same time. Do not use JavaScript `addFilter('blocks.registerBlockType', ...);` for dynamic blocks.

**PHP**

```php
/**
 * Customize register_block_type_args for 'core/rss' block
 */
function my_plugin_rss_block_type_args($args, $name)
{
    if ($name == 'core/rss') {
        // Replace render callback with our own function to fetch RSS 
        $args['render_callback'] = 'my_plugin_rss_render_callback';

        // Define extra 'datatext' attribute
        $extra_attributes = array(
            "datatext" => array(
                "type" => "string",
                "default" => "test"
            )
        );

        // Add the extra attribute to existing block attributes
        $args['attributes'] = array_merge($args['attributes'], $extra_attributes);
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter('register_block_type_args', 'my_plugin_rss_block_type_args', null, 2);


/**
 * Custom render callback for RSS block
 */
function my_plugin_rss_render_callback($attributes)
{
    // Use the core implementation of render_block_core_rss( $attributes ) 
    // as your template then modify the code needed to retrieve the RSS feed
   
    // Access new 'datatext' attribute
    $datatext = $attributes['datatext'] ? $attributes['datatext'] : '';

    return sprintf('<h2>%s</h2><ul %s>%s</ul>', $datatext, $wrapper_attributes, $list_items);
}
```

Ref: `core/rss` [render callback](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/37d98396f63dd7463287fd9d2124a179a1f68458/packages/block-library/src/rss/index.php#L15) function.

**JavaScript**

```js
// Add UI Control to edit extra attribute in Editor
const withDatatextControl = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
    return (props) => {

        if (props.name !== 'core/rss') {
            return (<BlockEdit {...props} />)
        }

        return (
            <>
                <BlockEdit {...props} />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody>
                        <TextControl
                            label="My Datatext"
                            value={props.attributes.datatext}
                            onChange={(value) => props.setAttributes({ datatext: value })}
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </>
        );
    };
}, 'withDatatextControl');

addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'core/rss',
    withDatatextControl
);
```

Comment: Hello @S.Walsh in PHP function that mirrors the default RSS render callback and also handles your extra parameter could you please elaborate more on that.

Comment: @raju_odi I've added an example of the render callback and how to resolve this issue via PHP filter to avoid the error, hope this helps?